# Client Server iPhone App Development

Tags: sql-server, xml, web-services, ios4

I've taken on a project of converting a data-driven website which functions kinda like Facebook on a smaller scale to a mobile app on the iPhone. The website runs SQL server on the app and I've been doing some research on how I can implement such a project. Of what I've found, it seems like web services is the way to go and given that the SQL server on the back end holds a lot of data, I'm leaning towards XML. Would this be the right way to go or is there another more efficient way of implementing this? I have limited experience as far as Web Services is concerned, can someone please advise me on this. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

XML/SOAP might be a bit bloated for a mobile application. JSON or a binary message would probably be preferable. I've had good luck with [RemObjects SDK](http://www.remobjectssdk.com/osx.aspx) and [Data Abstract for Xcode](http://www.remobjects.com/da/xcode.aspx). They allow you to handle SOAP (such as WCF servers) if needed. You can use Data Abstract to work with data from a remote SQL server as well.

Comment: I was hoping to find a solution that wasn't so expensive. Is there a cheaper way to achieve this kind of an implementation? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks